# UITabBar backgroundImage not showing on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm setting the `UITabBar backgroundImage` like this:

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_tab_bar"]];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

It works on iOS 8 but on iOS 7 it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was happening. I only had `ic_tab_bar@3x.png` asset for the background image and for some reason it wasn't downscaling it so I added the 1x and 2x assets and it started to show up. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

try  like  this  maybe can help you

```
 [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_tab_bar"];
```

Comment: Thank you but this didn't fix my problem, I finally found a solution, check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32460153/1801237.